# Forcing JavaScript to refresh once

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I force Javascript to refresh onload only once? My take:

```
$(window).ready(function(res){
    var hash = '#refreshed';
    if(window.location.hash != hash) window.location.replace(window.location + hash)
});
```

But this doesn't refresh the page.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of a hash is that changing it won't reload the page.

As of that you would need to use [MDN: Location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) after you changed the hash.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [`location.reload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)?

> The Location.reload() method Reloads the resource from the current
>   URL. Its optional unique parameter is a Boolean, which, when it is
>   true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is
>   false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its
>   cache.

Example:

```
$(window).ready(function(res){
  var hash = '#refreshed';
  if(window.location.hash != hash) {
    window.location.replace(window.location + hash); // add your hash
    document.location.reload();                      // reload the page
  }
});
```